# Position Relative & Absolute in Sections - Relative Sections Interfere with each other?

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I tried to create a chat with a couple of messages. I used relative message wrappers containing an absolute-position picture section and an absolute-section message text. However, for some reason, each relative message wrapper cuts into a different one.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Check the snippet below to reference.

```css
.message-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.profile-image-section-left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.message-content-left {
  background: black;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 9px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: -15px;
}

.profile-image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.profile-image-section-right {
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}

.message-content-right {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 9px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card">
  <div class="message-wrapper">
    <span class="profile-image-section-left">
                <img class="profile-image" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/ios-logo.png">
            </span>
    <div class="message-content-left">
      askjb sadkjbaskjb asdjbaskjbfas kadsjbkasjbf
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-wrapper">
    <span class="profile-image-section-right">
                <img class="profile-image" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/ios-logo.png">
            </span>
    <div class="message-content-right">
      askjb sadkjbaskjb asdjbaskjbfas kadsjbkasjbf
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-wrapper">
    <span class="profile-image-section-left">
                <img class="profile-image" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/ios-logo.png">
            </span>
    <div class="message-content-left">
      askjb sadkjbaskjb asdjbaskjbfas kadsjbkasjbf
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and some minor alterations to your right/left classes.

I attached a `.left` and `.right` class to your `.content-wrapper`s to indicate position to help reduce the style rules and offer a cleaner approach. Hope this helps you out!

### Example

```css
.message-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.message-wrapper.left {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.message-wrapper.right {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.profile-image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.profile-image-section {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.message-content {
  background: black;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 9px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card">
  <div class="message-wrapper left">
    <span class="profile-image-section">
        <img class="profile-image" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/ios-logo.png">
    </span>
    <div class="message-content">
      askjb sadkjbaskjb asdjbaskjbfas kadsjbkasjbf
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-wrapper right">
    <span class="profile-image-section">
        <img class="profile-image" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/ios-logo.png">
    </span>
    <div class="message-content">
      askjb sadkjbaskjb asdjbaskjbfas kadsjbkasjbf
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-wrapper left">
    <span class="profile-image-section">
        <img class="profile-image" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/ios-logo.png">
    </span>
    <div class="message-content">
      askjb sadkjbaskjb asdjbaskjbfas kadsjbkasjbf
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Additional Resources

- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)